# laravel 7 profile udpate wiith email unique:users

Tags: laravel, validation, unique, laravel-7, rules

I am trying to update the user profile. Everything works good but when i try to update name without updating the email. It gives an error saying the email already exists.
I have tried the method in the docs too but it does not work. I am using laravel 7
Here is my code

```
        $userId = auth()->user()->id;
    $validate = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($userId)],
        'password' => 'required|',
    ]);

    $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    $password = $request->password;

    $user::create([
        'name' => $validate['name'],
        'email' => $validate['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($password),
    ]);
```

Note: I just fixed it

I was not updating the profile i was creating a new one. I was using $user::create but this code creates another row in table the which is why the validation was not working so i replaced it with this code

```
       $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
```

Now it works.

Comment: `['sometimes','required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($userId)],` add `sometimes`

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: Try this `'email' => ['required','unique:users,email,' . $userId,],`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **update** in place of **create** like this:

```
$user::update([
    'name' => $validate['name'],
    'email' => $validate['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($password),
]);
```